# ReactCSSTransitionGroup enter animation not working, exit is working fine

Tags: reactjs, animation, modal-dialog, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am creating a reusable modal, and everything is working but when I actually call the component, the enter transition is not working. Exit works perfectly. I get the error:

> warning.js:45 Warning: Failed propType: transitionLeaveTimeout wasn't
>   supplied to ReactCSSTransitionGroup: this can cause unreliable
>   animations and won't be supported in a future version of React.Check
>   the render method of Modal

I have supplied enter and leave timeouts as instructed and still no luck.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import '../../modal.css';

const Modal = React.createClass({
    render(){
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            return (
              <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={400} transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>
               <div className="ui-modal" key={this.props.transitionName} {...this.props}> 
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            );
        } else {
            return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} />;
        }
    }
});

const UiModal = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return { isModalOpen: false };
    },

    openModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    },

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
    },

    setModalSize() {
        this.setState({ isModalLarge: false });
    },

    render() {
        const { openBtnText, header, subHeader, body, footer, optionalFooterText, closeBtnText, size } = this.props;
         const modalSize = size === 'large' ? 'ui-modal-large' : 'ui-modal-small';

        return (
          <div className="ui-modal-trigger-container">
            <h1>Modal small enter from bottom</h1>
            <div className="button" onClick={this.openModal}>{ this.props.openBtnText }</div>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim" id={modalSize}>
              <h1 className="ui-modal-header">{header}</h1>
              <div className="ui-modal-subheader">{subHeader}</div>
              <div className="ui-modal-body">
                {body}
              </div>
              <div className="ui-modal-footer">
                <div className="ui-modal-footer-button-group">
                  <div className="ui-modal-footer-button button" onClick={this.closeModal}>{closeBtnText}</div>
                  <div className="ui-modal-optional-footer-text" onClick={this.closeModal}>{optionalFooterText}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

export default UiModal;
```

The only information I get back in the console is:

> warning.js:45 Warning: Failed propType: transitionLeaveTimeout wasn't
>   supplied to ReactCSSTransitionGroup: this can cause unreliable
>   animations and won't be supported in a future version of React.Check
>   the render method of Modal

I am unsure how to fix since I have provided enter and leave timeouts already and it does not fix the issue.

The CSS for the modal is below:

```
.ui-modal-trigger-container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.ui-modal {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70%;
    left: 35%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
    background: white;
}

#ui-modal-small {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70%;
    left: 35%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
    background: white;
}

#ui-modal-large {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8%;
    left:0%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: white;
}

.ui-modal-header {
    font-family: 'Flexo';
    font-size: 28px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ui-modal-subheader {
    font-family: 'Flexo';
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ui-modal-body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.ui-modal-footer {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.ui-modal-footer-button-group {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.ui-modal-footer-button {
    float: right;
}

.ui-modal-optional-footer-text {
    float: left;
    color: #4099D4;
    font-style: italic;
}

.modal-anim-enter {
    opacity: 0.00;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.modal-anim-enter.modal-anim-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.modal-anim-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.modal-anim-leave.modal-anim-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.00;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Comment: you still get the same error you have posted? Can you post your css as well as the transitionName?